# How to delete the Boot Camp partition from the VM Library

Tags: vmware-fusion

I migrated the bootcamp partition as my first VM then later created a completely new VM within Fusion. I would now like to delete the bootcamp VM but cannot find how to do so.

Help please

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Documents -> Virtual Machines folder where VM's are typically stored. The boot camp VM uses the actual hard disk partition of the Windows installation. So to completely remove this, you have to also remove/erase/resize the Windows partition as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a superuser.com quesiton, please read the SF FAQ.

Either way just go into OSX's 'Disk Utility', find you disk, look at the partitions, find the boot camp partition, delete it - you'll probably want to grow the OSX partition with the freed-up space too I imagine.